# If $A \times B$ is closed is A necessarily closed?

Tags: general-topology

Here the operation $\times$ denotes cartesian product. I have sets $A$ and $B$ in real numbers.

Answer seema that it need not be closed, can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B$ is nonempty then $A$ must be closed, because if $b \in B$ then $A$ is the inverse image of $A \times B$ by the map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2, x \mapsto (x,b)$. But if $B$ is empty then $A$ can be arbitrary (because $A \times B$ is empty), and may not be closed.

Comment: But isnt an empty set both closed and both open?

Comment: @Xenidia To clarify: If $A$ is *any* set and $B$ is empty, then $A \times B$ is empty, and therefore closed. So a counterexample is obtained when $A$ is not closed and $B$ is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A,B$ are non-empty subsets of $R$. Note for any sequence $\{(a_n,b_n)\}_1^\infty; x_n \in A, y_n \in B$ for all $n$, the sequence converges (in $R^2$) if and only if it converges coordinate-wise. Suppose it converges to $(x,y) \in R^2$, then $(x,y) \in A \times B$ by assumption, and hence $x \in A$.

Now fix a sequence $\{a_n\}_1^\infty \subset A$ that is Cauchy/converges to some $x \in R$. Can you think of a sequence $\{(a_n,b_n)\}$ in $A \times B$ that is also Cauchy? What will it converge to? What can you conclude?